# Magento failing when trying to save product inside event observer on frontend?

Tags: product, event-observer, frontend, product-attribute

I have a function that is tied to an event observer

One of the requirements is that when it loops through the order item data, if a certain product attribute is empty it issues a request to get specific data through a separate model (working fine).

the problem code basically boils down to this

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $key => $item) {
    /** @var Tantor_Catalog_Model_Product $productData */
    $productData = $item->getProduct();
    $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productData->getId());
    $_item->setNetsuiteItemIid('foo');
    $_item->save();
}
```

however Magento is throwing an exception of

```
2014-03-05T21:14:14+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1180' in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1180): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/html/a...', 1180, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1123): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_collectSaveData(Object(Tantor_Catalog_Model_Product))
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Tantor_Catalog_Model_Product))
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Tantor/Netsuite/Model/Observer.php(218): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Tantor_Netsuite_Model_Observer->saveOrder(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Tantor_Netsuite_Model_Observer), 'saveOrder', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_pla...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1096): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_pla...', Array)
#8 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(774): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(511): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#15 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#16 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#17 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /var/www/html/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}
```

Why would i be able to use identical code in a 3rd party script outside the magento observer just fine, but when I try to run it inside that observer, it fails with that random error message?

Comment: This error is typical of a non-array being parsed into `foreach`.  The stack trace shows you an event is dispatched and the observer is faulty.  Are you sure `$order->getAllItems()` is retuning an `array()`?  use: `Zend_Debug::dump($order->getAllItems());`.  However, it might be another observer with some bad code?

Comment: the problem is with Magento core code, not with my snippet at the top.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not allowed to save products from the frontend.

This is done through the fact, that when you load a product in frontend, the `origData` property is not filled:

```
public function setOrigData($key=null, $data=null)
{
    if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        return parent::setOrigData($key, $data);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So when you try to save the product, the error you describe is raised.

You can solve this problem either when you change the current store to admin, e.g.  with the code  from @magboy:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

better using `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation`

And my prefered solution is to extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and replace the `setOrigData` method

```
public function setOrigData($key = null, $data = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        $this->_origData = $this->_data;
    } else {
        $this->_origData[$key] = $data;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I'm **NOT** talking about a rewrite here! Only use your model on this one place to enable saving. Then you have the security-feature still active everywhere else.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this line of code:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

I'm not sure why you have to do this now in the current version of Magento. Maybe someone else can explain?

Comment: after I set the currentstore to Admin and saved the product, do I have to set it back to the original value ?

Comment: @Giuseppe It depends what you are doing later on with the request; it's cleaner and will lead to less issues if you do it